# Force widgetlocker theme's default image?

Tags: lock-screens, themes

I'm trying to get WidgetLocker to work with an "[Xperia ICS](https://www.box.com/s/bb8e71be312fb45b18b3)" theme. So far the theme looks good but I have a bit of issue about the right slider.

[image]

As you can see above, the right Camera slider looks just fine. However, instead of launching the Camera app, I want it to instead run a Tasker task that captures images instantly. I have the task already setup and its working fine.

But when I select it to be the action for the right slider, it obviously uses the icon I set to it by default.

[image]

So I went and extracted the right slider image from the theme zip file in an attempt to restore the slider back to how it looked like on the first image. However, when I selected the right slider image, it doesn't fit nicely and thus makes it look smaller than the left slider.

[image]

And so my question is, how do I make it look like how it was on the first image while opening a Tasker task instead of launching the Camera app?